# Auto populate fields from one Vf Page to another VF page

Tags: visualforce

i have Two VF Pages(REGISTRATION PAGE,Questionnaire Page)in REGISTRATION PAGE i have one field called as email id i need that field to auto populate in Questionnaire Page is it possible any one please share your coding to achieve that..

Comment: Should be possible, you can pass as a query parameter. I don't have any code for it.

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) about page references. You can learn how to put and get a parameter to a page.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in your page navigation

```
 {! URLFOR($Page.Questionnaire, null, ['email'='email-you-want-to-send'] ) }
```

and use below code in your Questionnaire controller to get the email

```
 String email = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('email');
```